# Flutter doctor is crashing on macos

Tags: dart, flutter

I follow [this guide](https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/install/macos#run-flutter-doctor). After unzip flutter I run `flutter doctor` and take an error

```
⡿Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: The method '<' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: <(Instance of 'Version')
```

Full stack

```
~/development/flutter/bin/flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Mac OS X 10.14.2 18C54, locale ru-RU)
    • Flutter version 1.0.0 at /Users/naumov_evg/development/flutter
    • Framework revision 5391447fae (6 weeks ago), 2018-11-29 19:41:26 -0800
    • Engine revision 7375a0f414
    • Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

⡿Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: The method '<' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: <(Instance of 'Version')
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:50:5)
#1      CocoaPods.evaluateCocoaPodsInstallation (package:flutter_tools/src/ios/cocoapods.dart:69:28)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      CocoaPodsValidator.validate (package:flutter_tools/src/ios/ios_workflow.dart:231:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      GroupedValidator.validate (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:304:52)
#4      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:49:6)
#5      GroupedValidator.validate (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:301:36)
#6      Doctor.startValidatorTasks (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:111:52)
#7      Doctor.diagnose (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:184:41)
#8      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:49:6)
#9      Doctor.diagnose (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:174:24)
#10     DoctorCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/doctor.dart:48:39)
#11     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:49:6)
#12     DoctorCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/doctor.dart:34:42)
#13     FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:401:18)
#14     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:77:64)
#15     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#16     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#17     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129:18)
#18     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:642:45)
#19     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:671:32)
#20     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:476:7)
#21     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#22     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:33:20)
#23     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#24     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#25     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
#26     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#27     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#28     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#29     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:172:5)
```

Comment: Was it a fresh install or an update? Which version of OSX do you have? Have you added flutter to your $PATH variable?

Comment: It is a fresh install. The version is 10.14.2 18C54. A flutter bin folder has added in the PATH variable